# Docker Swarm ping by hostname incremental host.<id>

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a service that requires that it can connect to the other instances of itself to establish a quorum.

The service has a environment variable like:

```
initialDiscoverMembers=db.1:5000,db.2:5000,db.3:5000
```

They can never find each other. I've tried logging into other containers and pinging other services by . like `ping redis.1` and it doesn't work.

Is there a way in Docker (swarm) to get the incremental hostname working for connection as well? I looked at the endpoint_mode: dnsrr but that doesn't seem to be what I want.

I think I may have to just create three separate instances of the service and name it different things, but that seems so cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot refer independently to each container using the incremental `host.<id>` since the DNS resolution on Swarm is done on a service-basis; what you can do is to add a `hostname` alias to each container based on its Swarm slot.

For example, right now you're using a `db` service, so you could add:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    db:
        image: postgres
        deploy:
          replicas: 3
        hostname: "db-{{.Task.Slot}}"
        ports:
          - 5000:5432
```

In this case, since all the containers within each Swarm `task` are in the same network, you can address them by `db-1`, `db-2` and `db-3`.

Comment: Thanks! this has gotten me really close. Using neo4j and having a problem with hazelcast, but finally got the ports to bind using this method.